# authenticated queue create/access with a name pattern with activemq

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-camel

Hi i want configure a activemq to secure queue access and creation.

```
client.<client-id>.sub
```

`client.<client-id>.pub`

And late create a Camel redirect to a unique queue adding client-id headers on message redirected

Any suggestion?

PS Please forget my english

Comment: What's the question?  What have you tried?  What hasn't worked?

Comment: I don't know how I do. I need a suggestions to make a poc (security handlers/strategies, listener, i dont know)

Answer (score 0):

The way you handle authorization to ActiveMQ queues and topics is by the authorizationPlugin on a prefix and user level.

```
<authorizationPlugin>
       <map>
         <authorizationMap>
           <authorizationEntries>
             <authorizationEntry queue="client.client123.>" read="client123" write="client123" admin="admins" />
             <authorizationEntry topic="client.client123.>" read="client123" write="client123" admin="admins"/>
              ... etc. for other clients.
           </authorizationEntries>
```

This assumes client123 is authenticated, by any [authentication mechanism](http://activemq.apache.org/security.html).

I don't follow how you want Camel to deal with the routing, but something like this is probably what you want to route from multiple client queues to one single queue with headers (just an example, you prob. have to modify it to fit your case a bit, with error handling and such.

Note the use of `>` for wild card queues.

```
 from("jms:queue:client.>")
        .process(new Processor(){
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                String queue = exchange.getIn().getHeader("JMSDestination").toString();
                // queue name is: queue://client.<client_id>.xx
                String clientId = queue.substring(queue.indexOf(".")+1);
                int idx = clientId.lastIndexOf(".");
                clientId = clientId.substring(0,idx);
                System.out.println("ClientID: " + clientId);
                exchange.getIn().setHeader("SendingClientId", clientId);
            }

        })
        .to("jms:queue:collector.queue");
```

Comment: -hi Petter, thanks for your answer. it is possible use a variable or wildcard for client-id? The client id is dynamic.

Comment: Hi, the routing is using a dynamic client id in my example.

For authorization, you need to configure each one, obviously